# How to call a variable in python using a wildcard on its name

Tags: python

I have a few variables with different names and values

```
var_1= 10, var_2 = 20  , var_4 = 40 , var_5 = 50
```

and I have a variable called `i` that has a value assigned in this case `i = 4`

how can select the variable with a wild card based on the value of `i`?

like in some programing languages like java it would be something like this

`select_value = var_+i`   the result of printing `selected_value` would be 40.

Thanks

Comment: Nothing like that would work in Java. I don't think any sane programming language would allow it either. What you need is a `list`, not multiple variables.

Comment: i guess u are asking to do something like variable1 = variable1 + i
and after passing several values u get different values of variable1. Well to do so u are asking for iterations and u can use any loop like while /for /if loop. and u don't need to specify particularly for i in python and u need to properly write for using various variables in a loop Hope it helped.

Comment: Absolutely that would not work in Java. In any case, you **definitely shouldn't be designing your program this way**. Instead of dynamically using variables like this, use a *container* like a list or a dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there are some un-pythonic or security issues with this method, but it gets the job done:

```py
eval(f"var_{i}")
```

Comment: Only a maniac would use this in a serious project lol

Comment: Like I said, I'm sure there are issues, but it does what OP wants

Comment: Please don't suggest bad programming practices. The OP has an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) which should be solved in a totally different way.

Comment: It's a good answer according to the OP's question

Comment: @Selcuk, can you explain what OP's actual problem is?

Comment: Their actual problem (X) is to have a variable number of values, and to be able to access them in an arbitrary order. Their solution (Y) to this is to create multiple variables, which is obviously an inferior method. Solving Y does not make sense, so we should focus on solving X instead.

Comment: Or, it's also possible that problem (X) is that OP has, fully outside his control, a group of variables named as such that would cause a second problem if OP wanted to say add them to a list in a particular order, or a dictionary, every time a new variable was delivered

Comment: That's also possible, although highly unlikely. I guess the OP is not interested in clarifying it either. In any case, blindly [suggesting `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) does not help anyone. For example `globals().get(f"var_{i}")` would be a safer (although equally bad) solution.

Answer (score 0):

At that point don't use variables and instead store them in a dictionary:

```
var = {
    'var_1': 10,
    'var_2': 20,
    'var_4': 40,
    'var_5': 50
}

print(var['var_4'])
>> 40
```

Comment: I believe `print(var[f'var_{i}'])` would be a better example.

Comment: This doesn't answer what OP is asking for, a dictionary with keys 1-4, then calling var[i] would be better

Comment: @goalie1998 this is a much better alternative than what the OP is trying to do.